# X won't run on certain machines using my custom debian live boot usb

Tags: graphics, x-server, x

I am workign on writing a custom live boot usb with Debian as base operating system.

The goal is for this to run on many unpredictable system configurations. Most computers are failing to run `startx` successfully.

On run I see this:

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.3
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux opswat-dev 4.19.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.28-2 (2019-03-15) x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz boot=live persistence quiet nomodeset
Build Date: 25 October 2018  06:15:23PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.3-1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Apr 17 21:22:21 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

/var/log/Xorg.0.log reports:

```
[  1410.694] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.3
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1410.697] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[  1410.698] Current Operating System: Linux opswat-dev 4.19.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.28-2 (2019-03-15) x86_64
[  1410.698] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz boot=live persistence quiet nomodeset
[  1410.700] Build Date: 25 October 2018  06:15:23PM
[  1410.701] xorg-server 2:1.20.3-1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[  1410.702] Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
[  1410.703]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1410.703] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1410.705] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Apr 17 21:31:09 2019
[  1410.706] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1410.706] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1410.706] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  1410.706] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  1410.706] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1410.706] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1410.706] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1410.706] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1410.706] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1410.706] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  1410.706] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc" does not exist.
[  1410.706]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1410.706] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  1410.706]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1410.706] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  1410.706]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1410.706] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  1410.706]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1410.706] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1" does not exist.
[  1410.706]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1410.706] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  1410.706]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1410.706] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1410.706]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1410.706] (==) FontPath set to:
    built-ins
[  1410.706] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1410.706] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  1410.706] (II) Loader magic: 0x5608ec5bbe20
[  1410.706] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1410.706]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1410.706]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[  1410.706]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  1410.706]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  1410.707] (++) using VT number 1

[  1410.710] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[  1410.711] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:0162:1028:0577 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf7800000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  1410.711] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1410.711] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1410.712] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1410.712]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  1410.712]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  1410.712] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[  1410.712] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[  1410.712] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[  1410.712] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  1410.712] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  1410.712] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  1410.712] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1410.712]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 1.20.3
[  1410.712]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1410.712]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  1410.712] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  1410.712] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  1410.712] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1410.712]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 0.5.0
[  1410.712]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1410.712]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  1410.712] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  1410.712] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  1410.712] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1410.712]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 2.4.0
[  1410.712]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1410.712]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  1410.712] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  1410.712] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  1410.712] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  1410.712] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  1410.712] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[  1410.712] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  1410.712] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  1410.712] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1410.712] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  1410.712] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1410.712]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 0.0.2
[  1410.712]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  1410.712] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[  1410.712] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  1410.712] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  1410.712] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1410.712] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  1410.712] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1410.712]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 0.0.2
[  1410.712]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  1410.712] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[  1410.712] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  1410.712] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  1410.712] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  1410.712] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  1410.713] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1410.713] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  1410.713] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[  1410.713] (EE) 
[  1410.713] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  1410.713] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  1410.713] (EE) 
[  1410.715] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I successfully run `startx` on a thinkpad t420 laptop. every other machine i've tested has failed. They're all using intel onboard graphics.